# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{5n^2 + 1}n\right) = \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{5n^2 + 1}n\right) = \infty$.

*Proof*: Suppose $M \in\mathbb{R}$. Note that
$$\frac{5n^2 + 1}n = 5n + \frac1n > 5n.$$
Choose $N>\max\{1, \frac M5\}$. Thus, for $n \geq N$ we have,
$$\frac{5n^2 + 1}n > M; \forall M\in\mathbb{R}. \text{ QED}$$

Is this proof sufficient?

Comment: Yes, that looks good.

Comment: It is good, but don't hesitate to simplify even more since $5n>n$ and it is then trivial to find the $M$ in question.

Comment: Ah yes. I like that :). @zwim

Comment: You have all the essential pieces. I would not write "$\forall M\in \mathbb R$" where you have it; what you have written just before that is a statement concerning an arbitrary $M \in \mathbb R,$ which justifies a statement in a somewhat different form starting with "$\forall M\in \mathbb R: \exists N \in \mathbb R: \ldots$". That is, after what you wrote you are ready to write the definition of a limit applied to your problem. If your instructor has been writing that final detail in other examples then I would include it, but otherwise I would just stop at $\frac{5n^2 + 1}n > M.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a minor issue we don’t need to assume $N>\max\{1, \frac M5\}$, we can simply require that

$$N>M/5 \implies 5n>M$$

or as suggested in the comments

$$N>M \implies 5n>M$$

and your proof is fine.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Your proof is sufficient and acceptable.

Basically, while dealing with limits such as these that is monotonic ones, it may actually suffice to show that the function is not bounded and that is what you have done.

Comment: 1) There is no function here. 2) Proving that the sequence is not bounded is not sufficient to prove that it tends to $+\infty$.

Comment: OMG, what are you saying! Don't you know that every sequence is a function?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you are right, but I guess the word "sequence" has been created to be used... Your edit is better now, but notice that the fact that the sequence is monotonic is (true, but) not so trivial (and you definitely don't need that to find the limit).